# Требуется считать текстовый файл, посчитать количество элементов в строке, найти последний и определить его первые 4 символа

Tags: php

Требуется считать текстовый файл, посчитать количество элементов в строке, найти последний и определить его первые 4 символа. С тем чтобы найти последнее слово проблем нет, но не получается сделать чтобы программа запоминала его, и далее выводила первые три символа из него.

```
    <?php

$files = file('country.txt');

foreach ($files as $string) {

echo str_word_count( $string, 0, "АаБбВвГгҐґДдЕеЁёЄєЖжЗзИиІіЇїЙйКкЛлМмНнОоПпРрСсТтУуФфХхЦцЧчШшЩщЬьЪъЫыЮюЬьЭэЯя" );

function myFunc($f) {
global $f
echo $f = substr($string,strrpos($string,' '),strlen($string));
return $f;
}
myFunc($f);

$NewFunc = "myFunc";
$NewFunc();
echo substr($NewFunc, 0, 3);

}
```

Comment: что это за код вообще с объявлением именованной функции в цикле ? он на второй итерации с фаталом упадет.

Comment: с такой формулировкой вам на фриланс биржу

Answer (score 0):

Для решения этой задачи не нужно использовать цикл:

```
$file = 'country.txt';
// считать текстовый файл
$arr = file_exists($file) ? file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES|FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES) : [];
// посчитать количество элементов
$all = count($arr);
// найти последнее слово
$end = explode(' ', $arr[$all-1]);
// вывести первые три символа из него
echo mb_substr(end($end), 0, 3);
```